# reading date from the excel file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem when I tried to read an excel file to PHP. I used the PHPExcel 1.7.7 version right now.

Here is a sample from the excel 2007 file (Column A for name, and column B for date)

```
Jim 9/17/2010
Gordon  6/4/1979
Bill    3/24/1987
Steve   5/24/1991
Robin   8/8/1964
```

I used this code to read the name and birthday:

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName = 'example.xls';

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format
';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

foreach ($sheetData as $row) {
echo $row['A'];
echo date_format(date_create_from_format('m-d-y', $row['B']), 'Y-m-d');
}
```

In the end it will print something like this

```
Jim     2010-09-17
Gordon  1979-06-04
Bill    1987-03-24
Steve   1991-05-24
Robin   2064-08-08
```

How do i change for the last part so the year would be 1964?

Answer (score 1):

Never used the function, but from checking its doc on php.net I think you can change this line:

```
echo date_format(date_create_from_format('m-d-y', $row['B']), 'Y-m-d');
```

to:

```
echo date_format(date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $row['B']), 'Y-m-d');
```

Reference:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date_format(date_create_from_format('m-d-y', $row['B']), 'Y');
```